# Kendo mvc grid InLine Edit Mode DateTimePicker Template gives Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I am using Kendo UI mvc grid for Data listing. I am making InLine Editing in this Grid.I am using EditorTemplate for DateTime field, so that it will give datetimepicker for DateTime field in InLine Edit Mode.When i am going to Click on Update button, it will give me Validation message like this : 'The  must be a date'

```
   columns.Bound(k => k.SevenDaysFrom).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("DateTime").Width(30);
                            columns.Bound(k => k.SevenDaysTo).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("DateTime").Width(30);
```

here DateTime in EditorTemplateName("DateTime") is the Template file i.e DateTime.cshtml
And this file will contain the Following code :

```
@model DateTime?
```

@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m))

Now it will give the validation error message while clicking on Update.The Belowe attach is the Validation error :

[image]

So, why this is happening is not known to me?
What is the solution for this ? Please Help.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the kendo culture:

```
@{
var culture = "en-GB";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/cultures/kendo.culture." + @culture + ".min.js")"></script>

<script>  kendo.culture("@culture"); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the data type in View Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<DateTime> SevenDaysFrom { get; set; }
```

and in kendo Grid you can mention like below,

```
columns.Bound(k => k.SevenDaysFrom).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")
```

refer my another answer 
[Display only datepicker in kendo inline editing not datetime picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082665/display-only-datepicker-in-kendo-inline-editing-not-datetime-picker)

Comment: Even with this, the issue is still there.