# Display only datepicker in kendo inline editing not datetime picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, inline-editing

I have an issue to disply the datepicker in kendo inline editing. It shows datetime picker all the times.

```
columns.Bound(k => k.datefrom).ClientTemplate("#= (datefrom == null) ? ' ' : kendo.toString(datefrom, 'dd.MM.yyyy') #").Width(150);
```

I also tried like this also

```
columns.Bound(k => k.datefrom).ClientTemplate("#= (datefrom == null) ? ' ' : kendo.toString(datefrom, 'dd.MM.yyyy') #").Format("{0:d}").Width(150);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the Model Property strictly to Date in View model using Data Annotations. 
In your view model,

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)] // making data type as date     
public Nullable<System.DateTime> datefrom { get; set; }
```

And in Kendo Grid,

```
columns.Bound(k => k.datefrom).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")
```

It works now :)