# Kendo grid - date field is non editable

Tags: c#, date, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo grid which has an 'end_date' column. The date is coming from server and it was getting converted to local timezone. To fix this issue I have used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242872/1054978)

Server side:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now();
string end_date = time.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

client side:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.end_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true))).Width(225);
```

But by using this approach , the `end_date` column in becoming non-editable. How can I make it editable and filterable?

Comment: Do you want inline Editable facility ?

Comment: yes inline Editable feature

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-field-binding-in-kendo-grid
Can you please check above link

Comment: thank you for the link , but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786922/kendo-mvc-grid-inline-edit-mode-datetimepicker-template-gives-error

Comment: Can you try to share a working example for better understanding the problem you are facing please?

Comment: the issue is resolved , please see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved

Model class

```
DateTime end_date {get;set;}

[DataType(DataType.Date)] // Annonate with this
string end_date_only = end_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

in cshtml: Use `end_date` and `end_date_only` as shown below with `ClientTemplate`

```
columns.Bound(c => c.end_date).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(end_date_only ), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true))).Title("End Date").Width(225);
```